# how do I start writing simple Json Rest enable server app in python

Tags: python

how do I start write simple (like Hello World) Json Rest enable server app in python, which I can run in Google App Engine.

Thanking you

Comment: Why would you want to do that?!

Comment: @Matt Joiner, I would like to use GAE for WebService.

Comment: Playing Json in Django is awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this project for a GAE rest application :
http://code.google.com/p/appengine-rest-server/

The documentation is good and there are some examples to understand how it works.
Very easy to use.